# Save the id of an object that I am creating in a foreign key of another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: `Activity` and `LocationActivity`.

`Activity` can have a kind of place, this place can be `room` or `location` and this information I keep in my table `location_activities` which has a foreign key `activity_id`.

I need that when creating an `activity` and choose the type of place I can save the id of the `activity` in `activity_id` of my table `location_activities`

```
def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)

    if params[:activity][:type_place_activity] == RoomEvent.name
        room_event = RoomEvent.find(params[:activity][:room_event][:id])
        location_activity = LocationActivity.new
        location_activity.activity_place = room_event
    end

      location_activity.activity_id = @activity

    if @activity.save
      render json: {status: 'created', message: 'Activity save'}
    else
      render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I have this code but the `location_activities` record is not saved in my database

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not saved because you only initialize it, but never save. Also you try to pass `@activtity.id` as foreign key before it is saved, in this moment `@activity` has no id. Should be:

```
def create
  @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)

  if @activity.save
    add_location(@activity)
    render json: {status: 'created', message: 'Activity save'}
  else
    render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private

def add_location(activity)
  return if params[:activity][:type_place_activity] != RoomEvent.name

  room_event = RoomEvent.find(params[:activity][:room_event][:id])
  activity.location_activities.create(activity_place: room_event)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Vasilisa's answer will solve the issue, I don't think that logic belongs in the controller. I would change the ActivitiesController like this:

```
def create
  @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
  if @activity.save_with_location_activities(params[:activity][:room_event][:id])
    render json: { status: 'created', message: 'Activity save' }
  else
    render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

And then add the save_with_location_activities method to the Activity model like this:

```
class Activity
  def save_with_location_activities(room_event_id)
    room_event = RoomEvent.find(room_event_id)
    if room_event && self.valid?
      save
      LocationActivity.create(activity: self, activity_place: room_event)
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What if `@activity` is invalid? Do we need to create `LocationActivity` in this case? And you forgot to check `params[:activity][:type_place_activity]`.

Comment: Now you don't want to save activity if it has no `room_event`, but it should be saved in any case

Comment: Maybe Alejandro must add some specifications on what to validate and what not.